# Multiple FORALL in a orasql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, procedure, forall

Im trying to both delete then update some data from a table inside a procedure.  It is my understanding that both can't be done in the same FORALL statement and that I can do multiple FORALL using the same cursor.  The problem is that the second FORALL does not seem to do anything.  Is there something that im not getting?  Here is the code :

```
cursor cPARTY is
    SELECT /* +parallel(4) */ DISTINCT p.ID,
    CASE WHEN sf.PARTYID is null THEN 'delete'
    ELSE 'switch'
    END AS action,
    pa.SOURCESYSTEMLID as sources
    FROM CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.EPUR_PARTY p
    LEFT JOIN CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.STAR_FILE sf ON sf.PARTYID = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY pa ON pa.ID = p.ID;

  type type_party is TABLE OF cPARTY%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  t_party type_party;

  nLOT pls_integer := 1;
  nbDeleted int :=0;
  nbSwitched int := 0;

begin
  p_tableName := 'PARTY(INDIVIDU)';
  allBEGIN_TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
  open cPARTY;

    loop
    lotBEGIN_TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
    dbms_application_info.set_module('CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY',trim(to_char(nLOT * nLIMIT,'999G999G999')));

    FETCH cPARTY BULK COLLECT
    INTO t_party
    limit nLIMIT;

    exit when t_party.count = 0;

    p_nbLinesTransfered :='Erreur: Suppression de donnÃƒÂ©es';
    dbms_application_info.set_module('CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY - DELETING',trim(to_char(nLOT * nLIMIT,'999G999G999')));
    FORALL i IN t_party.FIRST .. t_party.LAST
      DELETE /*+parallel(4)*/ FROM CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY 
    WHERE ID = t_party(i).ID
    AND t_party(i).action = 'delete';

    nbDeleted := nbDeleted + sql%rowcount;

  FORALL i IN t_party.FIRST .. t_party.LAST
    UPDATE CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY 
    SET UPDATEDATE = sysdate, SOURCESYSTEMLID = 'SOURCE_SYSTEM:0000000000', UPDATEDBYUSERID = 'CV_CLAIM_INTEG'
    WHERE ID = t_party(i).ID
    AND t_party(i).sources='SOURCE_SYSTEM:0000000004'
    AND t_party(i).action = 'switch'; 
    nbSwitched := nbSwitched + sql%rowcount;
    commit;

    lotEND_TIMESTAMP :=systimestamp;
    trc.trc_message('lotELAPSED '||to_char(nLOT * nLIMIT,'999G999G990')||' Rows. ELAPSED '|| replace(substr(to_char(lotEND_TIMESTAMP - lotBEGIN_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),1,20),'+000000 ','+'));
    nLOT := nLOT + 1;
  end loop;
  close cPARTY;
  commit;
  gather_stats('CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL', 'PARTY');
```

Comment: You should start by running the SQL which drives the cursor and see whether you do in fact have any records which match the UPDATE criteria. Also, you maintain some counts but don't do anything with them (at least in the snippet you've posted). You should include them in trace output messages so you can see what's occuring.

Comment: I did run the SQL of my cursor and every result is switch (wich i higly doubt it should be) but nevertheless only the deleting part occur wich technicaly it should not.

Comment: The update contains this condition: `AND t_party(i).sources='SOURCE_SYSTEM:0000000004'`. But in the source query you are doing LEFT JOIN, so the column `pa.SOURCESYSTEMLID as sources` could be different than this string `'SOURCE_SYSTEM:0000000004'`, could also be NULL. In such cases the update doesn't update anything.

Comment: Thats good, because if the pa.SOURCESYSTEMLID is null then I don't want to touch it.  But what I don't understand is why my action is always switch?